# Valid rules in CSG

Tags: formal-languages, context-sensitive

In the book of Hopcroft-Ullman (the 1979 edition) there is a rule $Da\rightarrow aaD$ in the example of the CSL language $a^{2^i}$.

Valid rules in CSG have the form $\alpha A \beta\rightarrow \alpha\psi\beta$. I think the mentioned rule is not valid, since there is no way to get rid of the terminal $a$ at the right side.

Or is there some magic that escapes me?

Answer (score 2):

What Hopcroft and Ullman call a context-sensitive grammar is nowadays called a [noncontracting grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar); see page 223. The two types of grammar are equivalent in power.